# how to replace the xml data based on other xml using xml parsing in pyspark or hive

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an 2 xmls in which one xml data should be update based onanother xml data,How can i update the xml data based on another xml data.
For example i have 2 xmls
xml1:A/B/C/D/E--value=5
xml2:A/B/C/D/E--actual value is 8..need to be replaced with 5.
Suggest me please with example how can i update the values using pyspark with xpath....or with hive?
I have checked hive with xpath with hive, we can fetch only records but not able to set using xpath?
We have xpath_string,xpath_int,xpath_double....but for fetching or updating the data do we have any other options?

Comment: Hi kumar, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask], which contains many helpful tips on how to write good, answerable questions. Your question as-is is poorly formatted, hard to read, and light on detail.

Comment: Hi Jeen,My question is simple to understand that can we update data in one xml based on  another xml data using pyspark or hive with xpath?